# Capture KeyCode and trigger event by base of HTML DIV in Aurelia

Tags: jquery, html, events, aurelia, keycode

I am working in Aurelia and I want to submit or cancel form by pressing function F4 and F10.My code is working fine under (window,document,element) but these are covering complete project body .I want to cover only specific area like as DIV container.When user press key from keyboard then event should be trigger.

I tried different solutions but nothing work in my scenario.(keydown,keyup or keypress) are not working if i target DIV id instead of element and getting error is that "Event Listener is not a function"

HTML

```
<template>
  <div class="container-fluid"  id.bind="abc">
First Name: <input type="text" ></br>
Last Name : <input type="text"></br>
 <div >
          <div class="col s12 right-align">
            <button  click.delegate="cancel()" >Cancel</button>
            <button  click.delegate="submit()" >Submit</button>
          </div>
        </div>
```

TS

```
private abc: any;
constructor(){
this.abc = "customer-div";
}

attached() {
   let __this = this;
     var myDIV = $("#" + __this.abc) as any;  
    (myDIV).addEventListener('keydown', this.handleKeyInput, true);
  }

  deactivate() {
let __this = this;
     var myDIV = $("#" + __this.abc) as any;
    myDIV.removeEventListener('keydown', this.handleKeyInput, true);
  }

 handleKeyInput = (event: { keyCode: number; }) => {

    console.log("Event is ", event);
    if (event.keyCode == 121) {
      this.submit();
    }
    else if (event.keyCode == 115) {
      this.cancel();
    }
  }
submit(){
console.log("form submitted");
}
cancel(){
console.log("Form cancelled");
}
```

when user press F4 or F10 then event should be triggered

Comment: Kindly give expert opinion.

Comment: why do you mix `aurelia` code with `jquery` code?

Comment: I tried different soultion to capture keycode on the base of DIV id .I followed this guide too but failed. https://ilikekillnerds.com/2016/02/using-event-listeners-in-aurelia/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've created a simple demo for you: [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/a-simple-component-08su7)

the demo is in `JS`, but you can convert it fairly easily back to `TS`.
notice multiple point:

1. you don't have to hook the events manually from the `TS/JS` code, you can use `.delegate` instead - this is the easy and right way to do it.
2. because of point #1, you don't have to bind the `id` anymore.
3. for a `div` to capture keyboard events, it has to be `targetable`. you can achieve that by adding `tabindex="0"` to the `div`. it will also add some styling when the `div` is selected - but we can fix that in `css`.

```html
<template>
  <style>
  div[tabindex]{
    outline: none;
  }
  </style>
  <div tabindex="0" keydown.delegate="handleKeyInput($event)">
    First Name: <input type="text"></br>
    Last Name : <input type="text"></br>
    <div class="col s12 right-align">
      <button  click.delegate="cancel()" >Cancel</button>
      <button  click.delegate="submit()" >Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

```
export class App {
  handleKeyInput(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 121) {
      this.submit();
    } else if (event.keyCode === 115) {
      this.cancel();
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }

  submit() {
    console.log("form submitted");
  }
  cancel() {
    console.log("Form cancelled");
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes this is the exact output which i want .You gave me a new idea to think,Thank you so much.

Comment: I have tested under TS and its working fine .again bundle of thanks.

Comment: I am facing one problem is that in submit case i have to press 2 times F10 key and in case cancel F4 is working fine on single press.

Comment: are you sure it's not a problem on your side? in the demo I created - this works even when pressing one time.

Comment: Problem was on my side .Your code is perfect and have no error .Thanks.